# Subclipse crashes eclipse photon on SVN access

Tags: eclipse, crash, repository, subclipse, photon

Eclipse Photon crashes immediately after accessing a SVN Server using Subclipse. Even opening the tree in reposity explorer crashes the Eclipse.
System: Linux Mint 18.2 
Eclipse Photon: actual version
Sublipse: actual version

Are there any logfiles to look for the cause?

Best regards

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Answer (score 0):

For it to crash, my guess is it happens inside the native Subversion API. You might try changing to SVNKit at least temporarily.  As a pure Java API you might get an error or exception but it is not going to crash the JVM.  See: https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki

Usually the JVM will produce a crash log and it might have clues such as stack traces that point to what crashed.  I have seen problems related to the gnome-keyring or KWallet support in SVN causing crashes.  Those can be turned off in your `~/.subversion/config` or `servers` files if that is the case and it could help.

As noted in https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki you should also make sure your native JavaHL library version matches up with the version required for Subclipse.  This will usually causes exceptions not crashes though.